# Cannot import Web3 from web3

Tags: web3.py

I've repeatedly installed web3 via pip on an ubuntu OS (17.04, running on a DigitalOcean droplet) but for some reason when I attempt to run "from web3 import Web3" I get this response:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web3'

I think it has to do with pip because I've had trouble installing other modules (eth-testrpc). Any advice?

Comment: If it's a pip problem with other libraries too, then you probably have an environment setup issue. You can work in a new virtual environment to sidestep it: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-programming-environment-on-an-ubuntu-16-04-server The upside is that you should really be working in python 3 anyway for web3.py

Comment: Thanks for the input, carver. I already ran this in a venv...no dice.

Comment: What do you see in your console in response to `pip install -U web3`?

Answer (score -1):

From the terminal, install Web3.py using pip with the following command:

```
pip install web3
```

To use the web3 library you will need to instantiate a `Web3` object:

```py
>>> from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider, IPCProvider
>>> web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

>>> web3.eth.blockNumber
4000000
```

or for an IPC based connection

```py
>>> web3 = Web3(IPCProvider())
```

Note that you should create only one RPCProvider per process, as it recycles underlying TCP/IP network connections between your process and Ethereum node.